# How to model a user that can be a host, customer, or both? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to rebuild something like airbnb as a side project and I'm wondering how to model a `User` entity that can be either a `Host`, a `Customer`, or both. How would one represent this?

The issue with polymorphism is that the `User` can only either a `Host` or a `Customer` but not both.

Is the best way to do this via two has-one relationships?

Comment: You might want to just use a separate model called `role` or something that can be used to tie different permissions to a user.  The one `role` can be` host`, one can be `customer`, but a user could also be both.  Just an idea

Comment: Would you attach ratings to the role as well? Like if a user can have separate ratings as a host or a customer... would that work?

Comment: I think ratings would `belong_to` to a user and a role, so `user.host.rating` could then return their host rating and `user.customer.rating` would be customer rating. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is by having three models: `User`, `Rental`,(home to rent), and `RentalBooking` (the booking a user makes)

A `User` has many `Rental`'s, and the `Rental` "host" would be determined by whoever owns the `Rental`(The rentals user_id). The `RentalBooking` would have a `rental_id` and a `user_id` (User ID being the customer).

Personally, I wouldn't necessary have a give the user a role of `Host` or `Customer`, but this information would easily be presentable in each booking or rental post.